# For each Hermitian operator $H $ the operator $U:=(H-iI)(H+iI)^{-1}$ is unitary.

Tags: functional-analysis

> For each Hermitian operator $H $ the operator $U:=(H-iI)(H+iI)^{-1}$ is unitary.

I've come up to this and don't know how to proceed.

$U^{H} = (H-iI)^{-1}(H+iI)$

$U^{H}U=(H-iI)^{-1}(H+iI)(H-iI)(H+iI)^{-1}$

Here it stops.

Comment: The only trick is to prove that $H+iI$ is indeed invertible. Other than that, $H-iI$ and $H+iI$ commute, etc...

Comment: Why do $H-iI$ and $H+iI$ commute?

Comment: $(H-iI)(H+iI)=(H+iI)(H-iI)=H^2+I$.

Comment: And you have a double typo in you $UU^*$. The last two exponents corresponding to $U$ are wrong. All this boils down to $(x^{-1})^*xx^*x^{-1}=x^{*-1}x^*xx^{-1}=1$.

Comment: Corrected it, thank you.

Comment: The sans serif font is very good for hermitian conjugates: $H^\mathsf H$ avoids the baffling appearance of a matrix in the superscript (e.g. $H^H$).